# get file content as a string in Servlet

Tags: java, html, xml, servlets

I am uploading a file using HTML form to a Servlet. Generally, I want to upload XML file, but the validation is done on the server side.

How can I get the content of the file as a string on the Servlet?

This is my HTML form:

```
<form action="xml" enctype="multipart/form-data">
Select XML file: <input data-theme="b" type="file" name="xmlFile" >
<input data-theme="b" id="xml" type="submit" value="Load">
</form>
```

This is my Servlet:

```
public class LoadFromXML extends HttpServlet {

    private BlackJackWebService_Service service;
    private BlackJackWebService BlackJackWB;

    /**
     * Processes requests for both HTTP <code>GET</code> and <code>POST</code>
     * methods.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        URL serverUrl = new URL("http://" + "localhost" + ":" + 8080 + "/bjapi/BlackJackWebService");
        service = new BlackJackWebService_Service(serverUrl);
        BlackJackWB = service.getBlackJackWebServicePort();
        String XMlFileContent = request.getParameter("xmlFile");
        boolean isDuplicate = false;
        boolean isValid = true;
        try {
            BlackJackWB.createGameFromXML(XMlFileContent);
        } catch (DuplicateGameName_Exception ex) {
            isDuplicate = true;
        } catch (InvalidParameters_Exception ex) {
            isValid = false;
        } catch (InvalidXML_Exception ex) {
            isValid = false;
        }
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        try {
            /* TODO output your page here. You may use following sample code. */
            out.println("<!DOCTYPE html>");
            out.println("<html>");
            out.println("<head>");
            out.println("<title>BlackJack</title>");
            out.println("<meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width, initial-scale=1\">");
            out.println("</head>");
            out.println("<body>");
            if (isDuplicate == false && isValid == true) {
                out.println("<h1 id=\"created\">" + " Game created" + "</h1>");
            } else if (isDuplicate == true) {
                out.println("<h1 id=\"created\">" + " Game already exist !" + "</h1>");
            } else if (isValid == false) {
                out.println("<h1 id=\"created\">" + " Invalid XML !" + "</h1>");
            }
            out.println("<form action=\"get_waiting_games\" method=\"get\">");
            out.println("<input data-theme=\"b\" type=\"submit\" value=\"Join a game\">");
            out.println("</form>");
            out.println("<form action=\"create_game.html\" method=\"get\">");
            out.println("<input data-theme=\"b\" type=\"submit\" value=\"Create another game\">");
            out.println("</form>");
            out.println("</body>");
            out.println("</html>");
        } finally {
            out.close();
        }
    }
```

Currently, I tried to get the file as a "parameter" - this returns null.

My goal is to upload the file, get its content as a string in the servlet and continue handling the string in the servlet.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to upload files to server using JSP/Servlet?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422468/how-to-upload-files-to-server-using-jsp-servlet)

Comment: this is for a file. I am looking for the String data of the file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

File Upload follows RFC [1687](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1867.txt) and sends a Multipart to the server (multipart/form-data)

To process the multipart server side, use an appropriate library such as Apache [Commons FileUpload](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload/)

Comment: I am using multipart/form-data in my HTMl form.

Comment: Yes but you are not processing it correctly server side. `request.getParameter()` is **not** the way to go. Check the Commons FileUpload docs

Comment: OK. Now, I am using annotation in my serlvet - @MultipartConfig

Comment: and I have this:         Part filePart = request.getPart("xmlFile");
        InputStream filecontent = filePart.getInputStream();
        String XMlFileContent = getStringFromInputStream(filecontent); I stil get 500 internal server error

Comment: Catch the exception server side and print the trace to see what triggers the 500

Comment: יונ 19, 2014 12:55:02 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [LoadFromXML] in context with path [/BlackJackMidServer] threw exception [org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase$InvalidContentTypeException: the request doesn't contain a multipart/form-data or multipart/mixed stream, content type header is null] with root cause
org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase$InvalidContentTypeException: the request doesn't contain a multipart/form-data or multipart/mixed stream, content type header is null

Comment: Try `<form action="xml" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">` and re-implement `doPost()`

Comment: still same exception on this line of code: Part filePart = request.getPart("xmlFile");

Comment: Strange that your content-type header is null. Any proxy/other soft on the way ? You will need to sniff the request and response. Check what your browser emits using the browser provided developer tools

Comment: Accept:text/html, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8,he;q=0.6
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:0
Cookie:JSESSIONID=1B5701E4B673E9278C464AB0B296B5F5
Host:localhost:8080
Origin:http://localhost:8080
Referer:http://localhost:8080/BlackJackMidServer/welcome.html
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.153 Safari/537.36
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest

Comment: looks like the content header is 0: Content-Length: 0

Answer (score 1):

You can use commons file upload to parse multipart request. Common file upload gives you a FileItem instance when you are done with request parsing. Fetch the input stream from FileItem instance and use the contents in your servlet.

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws  ServletException, IOException {
    DiskFileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
    ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);
    // Parse the request
    List<FileItem> items = upload.parseRequest(request);
    for (FileItem item : items){
        InputStream in = item.getInputStream();
        //Use in here
    }
}
```

Comment: items = upload.parseRequest(request); this is illegal

Comment: Refer to documentation of [commons file upload](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload/using.html)